# PowerApps - Two Lookup Columns Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, filter, powerapps-canvas, conditional

I have a canvas app connected to a SharePoint list that contains 2 Lookup columns: `Name` and `Code`.  There are about 600 line items.  In the app I have these two fields side by side, and basically want the two fields to reference each other.

For example: If I select a `Name` in the first lookup, I want that other Lookup (`Code`) to display the Code associated with the selected name.  So if one of my entries in SharePoint has Chris for the `Name`, and 01234 for the `Code` - I need the `Code` field to auto-populate 01234 if I selected Chris from the name field.

I hope this makes sense.  Nothing I've tried seems to work.

Thank you for the help!